# Dimension of garden to minimize cost

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, word-problem

Math question: A homeowner wants to build, along her driveway, a garden surrounded by a fence. If the garden is to be $5000$ square ft, and the fence along the driveway cost $6$ dollars per foot while on the other three sides it cost only $\$2$ per foot, find the dimension that will minimize the cost. Also find the minimum cost.

this is what I got so far: $X=6, H=2, \  V=5000ft^2, \ V=x^2h, \ C=36x^2+8xh$

Comment: Please don't pick labels if you don't know what they mean.

Comment: It said it dealt with optimizations, so I thought that was it. sorry didn't mean to offend.

Comment: Where does $V = x^2 h$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=5000$, length of the side along driveway$=x$ and width $=y$.

Then $A=xy=5000$. Total cost $\displaystyle =C=6x+2(x+2y)=8x+\frac{4\times 5000}{x}$. Now we have to find $x$ that minimizes $C$. So differentiating $C$ w.r.t. $x$ and equating it to $0$,

$\displaystyle \frac{dC}{dx}=8-\frac{20000}{x^2}=0\Rightarrow x^2=2500 \Rightarrow x=50$. When $\displaystyle x>50, \frac{dC}{dx}>0 $ and when $\displaystyle x<50, \frac{dC}{dx}<0 $. Hence, $C$ has a minimum at $x=50$. So $y=100$.

Comment: Thank you!! I understand now

Comment: @4ever, the way to thank someone on this website is, if the post answers your question, to "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.